Can't create Reserve for Token Lending's market
I am currently following the SLP Token Lending step by step (https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token-lending/cli/README.md) in order to deploy my own lending system for my token.
I have been able to deploy a Token2022 and create a Market on the lending program but I can't succeed at creating the reserve. Whenever I run the following command :
spl-token-lending \
  --program      6TvznH3B2e3p2mbhufNBpgSrLx6UkgvxtVQvopEZ2kuH \
  add-reserve \
  --market-owner owner.json \
  --source-owner owner.json \
  --market       nezy5Amk9WhzybXa73rcm2FPzBXWzH4tt5mWFUL6smT \
  --source       CNpSc59dN5E1ZPyc8u4U8eVfzS2JRQB7iAbZLbGzzuWj \
  --amount       250.0  \
  --pyth-product 6NpdXrQEpmDZ3jZKmM2rhdmkd3H6QAk23j2x8bkXcHKA \
  --pyth-price   5SSkXsEKQepHHAewytPVwdej4epN1nxgLVM84L4KXgy7

I get the following error :
AccountNotFound: pubkey=4uQeWaKunQWS92crEZmDgLMACd7LMyZd7gB6tzt2Dsm
I get this error no matter what I put as Oracle addresses / token address
Note: For the Oracle I tried the values from the tutorial and also the ones here and there(I used USDC values on Devnet contract)
I'd gladly enjoy any help on this please !

Unfortunately, I don't think token-lending will work with token-2022 out of the box. You'll need to modify the program following the guide at https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/onchain -- as for the specific issue you're seeing, you'll need to see what 4uQeWaKunQWS92crEZmDgLMACd7LMyZd7gB6tzt2Dsm corresponds to -- it's tough to tell from the info given
